# Move fix-commit from one branch to another, before merging them

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-history-graph

Working on an incomplete `feature` branch I already committed a `Fix` for `master`.

```
(master)    A-B-C
(feature)        \_D-E-Fix-G-H
```

How do I get the `Fix` commit onto `master`, ...

```
(master)    A-B-C------Fix'
(feature)        \_D-E-Fix-G-H
```

... but still being able to merge/rebase my `feature` branch on `master`?

```
(master)    A-B-C-D-E-Fix-G-H
```

I suppose `Fix'` should maintain the same SHA of `Fix` in order to not be seen a total different commit and be merged/rebased smoothly (so `cherry-pick`, that I usually use, is not helpful here).
So maybe it is not possible, but I am curious if there is any way to share some temporary fixes from a branch with another branch, and still be able to merge later the rest of the missing commits.

My `feature` branch is just a local one. Naturally I want to avoid rewriting the history.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Fix` commit is cherry-pickable, then it's independent of `D` and `E`, so you could `git rebase -i C` and reorder your history to put `Fix` behind `D`.

Then it would be easy to merge the feature branch back into master.

```
(master)    A-B-C--Fix'
(feature)        \_Fix-D-E-G-H
```

You mentioned you wanted to avoid rewriting history, but if you are okay with picking out a single fix commit, I think reordering your feature branch to make it more easily mergable should be acceptable.

Comment: Usually I already ```cherry-pick``` to solve this issue quickly. Then when merging/rebasing it'll see already the fixing code so it will just do nothing. And it's rather fine. Mine was more a curiosity about keeping the same commit as common among the branches, without having to duplicate it in ```Fix'``` (_is it possible to put ```D``` and ```E``` between ```C``` and ```Fix```, later, after having put ```Fix``` after ```C``` in ```master```?_ Isn't the only requirement, in order to not rewrite the history, that either ```Fix```, ```D``` and ```E``` keep the same ancestors?)

Comment: Not that I know of, if you kept `D` and `E` between `C` and `Fix`, but also had `Fix'` in `master`, then merging should create a merge commit `I`, with two parents, and two apparent copies of `Fix`. I dislike merge commits more than I dislike editing history, so I usually go with the latter.